# Как передать путь файла из TextBox в переменную в другом классе

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как из `TextBox` передать путь в другой клас в переменную `path`?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.Title = "Выберите файл";
                ofd.Filter = "Текстовые файлы|*.txt";
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
            }
}

public class text
{
    public void SplitAndQuery()
            {
                    string path = @"D:\text\text.txt";
                    char[] separatorLines = { '\n' };
                    char[] separatorWords = { ';' };
                    string[] lines = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default).Split(separatorLines, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                         //code
                    }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class text
{
  public void SplitAndQuery(string path)
  {
    char[] separatorLines = { '\n' };
    char[] separatorWords = { ';' };
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default).Split(separatorLines, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length - 1; i++)
    {
      //code
    }
  }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
  ...
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    text t = new text();
    t.SplitAndQuery(textBox1.Text);
  }
}
```